# How can i check if the first letter of a word/string is a specific letter using php?

Tags: php

As per the question title i want to check if the first letter of a given word/string is equal to letter "a" using php. I know already how to check if a word contain the letter "a" using the code below:

```
$word='car';
if (stripos($word, "a") !== false) {
   //THEN DO SOMETHING
 }
```

But how can i check if the first letter of the word "car" is equal to "a" ?

Comment: You can access the first character in a string like an array using `[]` i.e. `if ($word[0] == "a") echo "equal";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go this way with it, provided as your example shows, the word in question begins the string:

```
$word='car';
if (substr(strtolower($word), 0, 1) == "a") {
    echo "yup";
}
else {
    echo "nope";
}

// echoes nope
```

*** Edit 1

> Is it possible to check for more than one letters ? For example if (substr(strtolower($word), 0, 1) == "a", "b")

```
$acceptableFirstLetters = "abc";
$word='Car';
if (strpos( $acceptableFirstLetters, strtolower(substr($word, 0, 1)) ) !== false) {
    echo "yup";
}
else {
    echo "nope";
}

// echoes yup
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfect for me. Just one more question. Is it possible to check for more than one letters ? For example  
if (substr(strtolower($word), 0, 1) == "a", "b") {

Comment: Well to go with a non-regex solution, you could very well use `strpos()`. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use index 0 on the string `$str[0] == 'a'`